# React Installation (npm WARN tarball tarball data for tar@^2.2.1, npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to install React. I've installed NodeJS.

After executing the following command `npm install -g create-react-app`, an error of this kind occurs-
(Please refer to the image link for better understanding)

[image: npm WARN tarball]

> npm WARN tarball tarball data for tar@^2.2.1
>   npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
>   npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting tar@^2.2.1:
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-04T18_12_42_283Z-debug.log

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with your local NPM, could you try running

[`npm clear cache --force`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html), [`npm clean`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-clean), and/or deleting your `package-lock.json` if you have it.

Then running `npm install -g create-react-app` again.

Additional resources:

- [NPM permissions page](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)
- [common NPM errors page](https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors)

Edit:

After some more digging around it seems like `create-react-app` is meant to be installed like using `npx`, please ensure that your version of `npm` is 5.2 or higher, here's the installation instructions from their docs:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

They also suggest to globally uninstall `create-react-app` if you've installed it (or in this case, tried to install it) just to make sure everything is up to date.

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm
>   install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package
>   using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses
>   the latest version.

Comment: I've deleted package-lock.json file. After executing the first command, I get the following- Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\Admin\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

Comment: Have you tried running `npm help config` to see more info? 

Here's more details on the `.npmrc` file that is mentioned in the error log: https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npmrc.html#global-config-file

I've also updated my original answer with another potential solution..

Comment: F:\r1>npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting tar@^2.2.1:

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-06T11_49_26_919Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

Comment: This is what it shows when I execute the create-react-app command- extract: WARN tarball tarball data for tar@^2.2.1 (sha512-FCEhQ/4rE1zYv9rYXJw/msRqsnmlje5jHP6huWeBZ704jUTy02c5AZyWujpMR1ax6mVw9NyJMfuK2CMDWVIfgA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more